# Reverse proxy for a subdirectory with nginx and Play 2.1 apps

Tags: nginx, playframework, reverse-proxy, playframework-2.1

### Goal

Setup multiple Play 2.1 applications with nginx using different subdirectory for each application.

App1 running on `127.0.0.1:4000` should be accessible under `127.0.0.1/dev`
App2 running on `127.0.0.1:5000` should be accessible under `127.0.0.1/test`

### Configuration

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    upstream app1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:4000;
    }

    upstream app2 {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /dev {
            rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://app1;
        }

        location /test {
            rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://app2;
        }        
    }
}
```

**App1 - application.conf**

```
application.context=/dev
```

**App2 - application.conf**

```
application.context=/test
```

### Problem

With this configuration I can access both applications, but only html code is loaded. All static files (css, js, images) aren't loaded.

I think this is caching problem. I've tried with different nginx parameters, without luck. If I request the site for the first time the browser responds (for `css` and `js` files, e.g. `127.0.0.1/dev/assets/stylesheets/main.css`) with status `200` but without content - `Content-Length: 0`. For the next time it responds with `304`, still without content.

I'm not sure if this is `nginx` or `Play 2.1` configuration problem.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local *domains* like `http://test.loc/` and `http://dev.loc` instead of relying on subfolders. Although `application.context` *should* work I saw many posts complaining that they don't...

What's more using *local domains* is more similar to the final - production enviroment, so it's just easier to debug some url depended things, like ie. cookies.

Comment: Thanks for this idea it is certainly interesting solution, but I would like to configure it with subfolders for production. I can see html content, so 'application.context' works for actions defined in controllers, but not for assets. As I said I'm not sure if it is nginx or play problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this doesn't directly answer your question, I got it to work in **HAProxy** by passing the `X-Script-Name` parameter:

```
frontend  public
  bind *:80
  use_backend playapp if { path_beg /playapp }

backend playapp
  acl is-ssl  dst_port 443
  reqadd X-Script-Name:\ /playapp
  reqadd X-Scheme:\ https  if is-ssl
  option forwardfor
  server playapp1 127.0.0.1:9000 check
```